# Confusion with Git. Should I push my changes to the repo from where I had cloned?

Tags: git, version-control

I think I might have not understood the Git method at all.I need to know that I am doing this right :
So I have cloned a git repository into my local machine so that I can contribute by adding some of my code , debugging ,etc,etc.

So I added this error handling to a file in the project and committed it on my local repo.
Should I be doing a  :

```
    **git push remote master**
```

so that the changes are committed on the server ?
I have set the my remote by doing a :

```
git remote add origin git@/the/actual/project/repository/at/gitHub
```

I don't want to mess with the project ,please guide me through this , I am new to the concept of Git.

Thank you
Deepankar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds right to me.

If you want to be really sure: fork the original repository that you cloned, clone that locally and test out your git push commands on the forked copy - not the original.

Edit: or even easier just make a super simple public repos and test your push/pull commands on that.

Great git references that saved me ('cos let's face it - Git is a lot harder than SVN)

http://gitimmersion.com/

http://try.github.com/levels/1/challenges/1

http://think-like-a-git.net/ -- the video on 'Git for ages 4 and up' really helped me get my head round it and is still my favorite resource.